# How to use keyboard shortcuts for hidden desktop shortcuts/icons?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, file-attributes, hidden-file

I created a shortcut on the desktop and assigned a Keyboard Shortcut to it from the properties menu to it. Now if I assign the hidden attribute, the shortcut gets hidden and Keyboard shortcut stops working. What can I do that the shortcut remains hidden but the keyboard shortcut works?

P.S. When you hide it, initially the keyboard shortcut works, but when you restart the computer, it doesn't thereafter.
I run Windows 8.1 Home Edition(Single Language)

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When hidden attribute is set to a file/folder, Windows explorer or Command Prompt will not show the file by default, and it will be invisible through the filesystem.

I think when you hide the shortcut, hot keys drivers still see it and run the shortcut, but when you reboot, hotkey drivers are re-loaded and stop seeing the shortcut then.

AFAIK it is normal for the hidden files to not run on when their hotkeys are hit after reboot or reload of hotkey drivers.

Comment: Thanks @Wasif Hasan for your valuable information. I found-out Auto Hotkeys yesterday and it works perfectly because I don't need shortcuts on my desktop anymore :-)

Comment: Ok welcome. If you like the information, please upvote it and accept by clicking the big tick mark and ^ looking button